# Turn off resolve peers in uTorrent server (utserver)

Tags: hostname, bittorrent, utorrent

I have `utserver` running and WebUI is also working. I noticed the default seems to have the peer resolve the IP address to their host name. I want to turn this off. In the Windows client, you could right-click and turn off Resolve Hostnames. No such option exists for WebUI. I also tried looking in settings under Advanced, hoping there would be something under the peer, but nothing about resolving host names seems to match. Is the default behavior to resolve hostnames only when the tab is open... or is the default behavior to always resolve the host name? I'd prefer to not resolve host name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a machine to install it on, but reviewing the code, 
In `web/js/webui/main.js`, this:

```
  $("mainInfoPane-peersTab").addEvent("mousedown", function(ev) {
    if (ev.isRightClick() && ev.target.hasClass("stable-body")) {
      utWebUI.showPeerMenu(ev);
    }
  });
```

should show a menu that has a call to `toggleResolveIP` which changes a setting `resolve_peerips`

So that may point you to the location in the UI, or you cn grep -r the configs for the runnign utserver for `resolve_peerips`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really following how to disable resolve peers. I don't need a GUI to toggle it on and off. I'm okay with hard coding it to have it off by default (always).